# Creating Dynamic radio button using the Id given and get the selected value

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

**Requirement**

This is the json I am having...

```
[
  {
    "id": 8651,
    "value": "Abdominal pain"
  },
  {
    "id": 8646,
    "value": "Chest pain"
  },
  {
    "id": 8642,
    "value": "Cough"
  }
]
```

Using this I need to create user with an option like this.

```
Abdominal pain  □ Yes       □ No
Cough   □ Yes       □ No
Chest pain  □ Yes       □ No
```

Once the use made the selection, Need to fetch for each Id which value is selected. like below.

```
[
  {
    "id": 8651,
    "selectedValue": "Y"
  },
  {
    "id": 8646,
    "selectedValue": "N"
  },
  {
    "id": 8642,
    "selectedValue": "Y"
  }
]
```

**What I tried**
Created a form entry like this

```
<form [formGroup]="symptomsForm">
   <div>
                <ul class="list-group">
                      <li class="list-group-item"  *ngFor="let obj of symptomsParams">
                      <span> {{obj.value}} </span> 
                        <span class="form-radio">
                          <input formControlName="{{obj.id}}" type="radio" /> 
                          <label>Yes</label>
                        </span>
                        <span class="form-radio">
                          <input formControlName="obj.id" type="radio" />
                          <label>No</label>
                        </span>
                      </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
</form>
```

It returns error... core.js:15723 ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: '8651'
{{obj.value}}, displays empty

component code

```
constructor() {

    this.symptomsForm = this.fb.group({
      symptoms: ['']
    });
}
```

This doesn't look like the correct way to achieve this, please suggest a way to achieve this requirement.

**Also, Requirement 2**

```
 [
      {
        "id": 8651,
        "value": "Abdominal pain",
        "selectedValue": "N"
      },
      {
        "id": 8646,
        "value": "Chest pain",
        "selectedValue": "N"
      },
      {
        "id": 8642,
        "value": "Cough",
        "selectedValue": "N"
      }
    ]
```

Then the list must be select the appropriate radio button selected

Comment: can you paste the code from your component. your HTML suggests you are using reactive forms, and are trying to access `FormControl` via formControlName. this is based on the formGroup being correctly initialized in the component. so if would helpful to see what you are doing in the component to get a complete picture.

Comment: @Edward ... I had updated the component code. I haven't done much, not getting a solution or how to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that the FormControl '8651' doesn't exist.

I expected to see a loop in your `ts` code to add a control for that number.

So, instead of

```
 this.symptomsForm = this.fb.group({
      symptoms: ['']
    });
```

I expected to see something that would do this or similar...

```
 this.symptomsForm = this.fb.group({
      8651: [false],
      // 8651: this.fb.control(false),
    });
```

note, I think array notation is same as the fb.control call, but double check the docs. I just added it to give a better explanation of what the .group is actually doing for you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have pasted here, I would strongly suggest that you read and walk through [Reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) in the docs

- in order to reference a formControl in your HTML the formControl has to have been created and added to the formGroup
- in your examples, you are trying to bind your HTML to form controls that haven't been created. this is the reason you are seeing the error.

For example

```
// the interface isn't required, but is useful for typechecking
export interface OptionI {
  id number,
  label: string
};

export class MyComponent {
  form: FormGroup;
  options: OptionI[];

  constructor( private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.options = [data]; // insert your data object here. you can hard code it to start, but eventually you'll probably want to get it from somewhere else.
    this.setupForm(this.options);
  }

  setupForm(options: OptionI[]) {
     const fg = {};
     data.forEach( (option: OptionI) => {
        // create the properties of the form control that will be passed to the form Builder.
        // treat the id as a string to ensure to avoid javascript treating the id as an index.
        fg[id+''] = [ false, Validators.required];
        // you the first value in the array is the default value for this control. in this case we are setting the default value to false
        // the Validators are optional in case you ever had more than a radio button
     };
     this.form = this.fb.group(fg);
  }
}
```

at this point you have dynamically created FormControls for each piece of data you need. you should now be able to user this in your HTML to access form control values.

```
<ul class="list-group">
   <li class="list-group-item"  *ngFor="let obj of options">
      <span> {{obj.label}} </span> 
      <span class="form-radio">
         <input [formControlName]="obj.id+''" type="radio" value="true" /> 
         <label>Yes</label>
      </span>
      <span class="form-radio">
        <input [formControlName]="obj.id+''" type="radio" value="false" />
        <label>No</label>
      </span>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Hope some of this was helpful. reactive forms are a very powerful way of creating dynamic forms for these types of scenarios. I would encourage you to review the link above from the Angular docs

good luck.